# How to customize dial pointer to an arrow in fusion charts?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I'm searching for customization of fusion charts dial pointer in angular gauge chart. I've gone through the all options provided in their documentation but none of them is for customization of dial pointer. I'm not sure that will it be possible or not directly through the options.

`Please refer below image i.e. what I want to achieve.`

[image: Angular Gauge chart]

I think I need to do modification in library code and that will be difficult.

Please suggest if any alternatives are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Try this [hack](http://jsfiddle.net/Pallab/wsk2fe54/2/).

```
"dials": {
    "dial": [{
        "radius": "70",
        "baseWidth": "40",
        "baseRadius": "25",
        "topWidth": "1",
        "rearExtension": "0",
        "value": "67"
    },
     {
        "radius": "48",
        "bgColor": "ffffff",
        "borderAlpha": "0",
        "baseWidth": "45",
        "baseRadius": "25",
        "topWidth": "40",
        "rearExtension": "2",
        "value": "67",
        "showValue": "0"
    }]
}
```

You should also explore their Annotation API for this kind of dynamic customization.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to catch click event in 2d pie chart (fusion chart). It should be AngularJS way.

Comment: Haven't tried, but FusionCharts has a AngularJS wrapper, that might help. Is it not possible to use the normal click events of FusionCharts ?

Comment: I want to use in angular way. I'm almost there using that angular wrapper. Please have a look if you can help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235942/events-is-not-working-in-angularjs-fusion-charts