# Display legend inside a pie chart with fusion chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I want to display legend with it's value inside pie chart. I googled it a lot but didn't get any solution. Also, there is no option in fusion charts to achieve this directly. Can anyone please suggest what trick can I apply to do so? I think I need to modify lot of things in library which I don't want so please help me.

`Refer below image`

[image]

I'm using angular-fusion charts library so I want to do this in angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FusionCharts you can achieve this using the attribute "placeValuesInside='1'"

```
// Sample data
{
"chart": {
    "showpercentagevalues": "1",
    "use3dlighting": "0",
    "showshadow": "0",
    "placevaluesinside": "1",
    "animation": "0"
},
"data": [{
        "label": "ST_Clean",
        "value": "33",
        "color": "f7bc34"
    }, {
        "label": "ST_Eff",
        "value": "67",
        "color": "e24b1a"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and works for me

```
"valuePosition"=>"inside",
"labelPosition"=>"inside",
```

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts

Answer (score 0):

You can place the value inside the slices by setting the value of the newly added attribute valuePosition to inside. The default value of valuePosition attribute is outside.

```
    {
    "chart": {
        ...
    },
    "data": [{
            "label": "Food",
            "value": "285040"
        },
        {
            "label": "Apparels",
            "value": "146330",
            "valuePosition": "inside"
        },
        {
            "label": "Electronics",
            "value": "105070"
        },
        {
            "label": "Household",
            "value": "49100"
        }
    ]
}
```

To know more about it - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#place-values-inside-the-pie-doughnut-chart

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/3dts9evm/